# Are there any tutorials on coding a parser for SVG files to be used by box2D?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, svg, box2d

I am trying to create an iPhone game with fairly large levels. Hard coding the platforms and physics objects is very time consuming. I have seen some people have made their own parsers for svg files to use in box2D, and Riq is selling levelSVG but it is a little pricey for me at the moment, and I only need basic features. Is there a tutorial on how to code a parser available online?

Comment: Also looking for something. If you do find something please let us know.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at [SVGQuartzRenderer](https://github.com/splashdust/SVGQuartzRenderer)?  It is designed to render SVG files in Quartz, so I imagine you might be able to pull out the SVG parsing code from this.  It's opensource, MIT license.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any tutorials but its fairly easy to do this using an XML parsing library. In my project I use MiniDOM to load an svg file and then I convert the elements into objects in the box2d word. The only thing that I had to do manually was the parsing of the path element.

Answer (score 1):

I've written an extensive tutorial on how to parse SVG files using Apache Batik SVG library. Included with the tutorial are a set of classes and a function I wrote in Java which will generate a set of Vec2 points given the location of the SVG file. If you're using Objective C you could try to port the scripts or at least get an idea of the process involved. The scripts support multiple paths per SVG file, transformations, straight lines and quadratic splines. The first tutorial in the series can be found [here](http://www.deluge.co/?q=node/2).